# Python script parameters for Integer not working

Tags: python-2.7, python-script-tool, parameters, integer

I am using a Python library called [arcpy_metadata](https://github.com/ucd-cws/arcpy_metadata) that uses 2 datatype called `max_scale` and `min_scale` that take integers: 
[image]

My code for that is just:

```
import arcpy, arcpy_metadata as md
....
min_scale = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)
max_scale = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(6)
....
metadata = md.MetadataEditor(file)
...
metadata. min_scale = min_scale
metadata.max_scale = max_scale
```

I am trying to turn this into a Python script in ArcMap toolbox. An example input for the max and min scale would 5000 and 150000000. Since there is no `integer` type and I don't really need decimals, I just entered `double` when configuring the parameters for the tool. I also set it as ``optional`. 
[image]

When I run the tool however, I keep getting the following error. What am I doing wrong here?

```
RuntimeWarning: Input value must be of type Integer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your inputs are strings, GetParameterasText is a string value.

convert that variable to an integer...

```
min_scale_int = int(min_scale)
max_scale_int = int(max_scale)
```

use your new variable in the rest of your code.

Comment: Arghhh! That totally worked! Can't believe I missed that. I guess I just assumed that if I entered an integer it would know it was an integer.